# Find support ticket number from String

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a custom pop client where I will get a no in subject like :

> Subject: What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please
>   reply as soon as possible

where **#1989768733736** is the ticket no. How to fetch the no from the string.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: use regex, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It looks like a task for us. Have you even tried to search any examples, tutorials how to parse string?

Comment: `string str = "What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please reply as soon as possible";

string ss = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("#") + 1, 14);`

Comment: it can 1 digit or some time can be 100 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to match any digit coming after the `#` character, eg `#(?<ticket>\d+)` to capture just the number or `#\d+` to capture the prefix as well as the number. This will capture the ticket number as the named group "ticket":

```
var regex = new Regex(@"#(?<ticket>\d+)");

var subject="What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please reply as soon as possible";

var ticket=regex.Match(subject).Groups["ticket"].Value;
```

Which returns `1989768733736`

The advantage of Regex is that it's thread safe so you can put it in a static field and reuse it from many threads, avoids creating temporary strings like String.Split and can handle very complex scenarios (like a `.` after the ticket) without hiccups.

If no match is found, the return value will be the empty string. If you want to explicitly check for a match you can use the Match.Success property:

```
var match=regex.Match(subject);
if (match.Success)
{
   var ticket = match.Groups["ticket"].Value;
   ...
}
```

The performance and memory gains of a Regex are very important in high traffic or high volume scenarios, like processing status emails, log entries, system responses and should be preferred even if they seem more complex.

Answer (score 4):

Use [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx):

*With undefined length of order-no:*

```
        var str = "Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736";
        var regex = new Regex("#[0-9-]*");

        var match = regex.Match(str);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

**Edit:**

*With defined length of order no:*

```
        var str = "What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please reply as soon as possible";
        var regex = new Regex(@"#[0-9]{13}");

        var match = regex.Match(str);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: Three problems here, the pattern will match single `#` characters, the pattern captures the prefix as well as the ticket number and finally, the digit class `\d` should be used to match digits.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos Thanks for the comment. Order no should have always the same length. Edited my answer so the regex won't match a single # nor a number with unsuitable length

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, if your all numbers are after `#` character and these numbers are always after first `#` character, you can use some [`String` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string s = "What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please reply as soon as possible";
int index = s.IndexOf("#");
s = s.Substring(index);
string number = s.Split(null)[0];
Console.WriteLine(number); // #1989768733736
```

Answer (score 1):

Subject: What is the Price of Dell Inspiration 4 #1989768733736 Please reply as soon as possible

where #1989768733736 is the ticket no. How to fetch the no from the string.

```
string str="#1989768733736";
int no;
no=convert.ToInt64(str.subtring(1,13));
```